# Using shell arrays to read every N lines in parallel of a file

Tags: bash, parallelism, bash-array

So, i already know how to successfully read every N lines in parallel, and run a command on each of those lines:

```bsh
while read -r i && read -r a && read -r b && read -r c && read -r d && read -r e && read -r f && read -r g && read -r h && read -r j && read -r k && read -r l && read -r m && read -r n && read -r o && read -r p && read -r q && read -r r && read -r s && read -r t && read -r u && read -r v && read -r w && read -r x && read -r z && read -r aa && read -r bb && read -r cc && read -r dd && read -r ee && read -r ff && read -r gg && read -r hh && read -r ii && read -r jj; do

                    dosomething "$i" &
                    dosomething "$a" &
                    dosomething "$b" &
                    dosomething "$c" &
                    dosomething "$d" &
                    dosomething "$e" &
                    dosomething "$f" &
                    dosomething "$g" &
                    dosomething "$h" &
                    dosomething "$j" &
                    dosomething "$k" &
                    dosomething "$l" &
                    dosomething "$m" &
                    dosomething "$n" &
                    dosomething "$o" &
                    dosomething "$p" &
                    dosomething "$q" &
                    dosomething "$r" &
                    dosomething "$s" &
                    dosomething "$t" &
                    dosomething "$u" &
                    dosomething "$v" &
                    dosomething "$w" &
                    dosomething "$x" &
                    dosomething "$z" &
                    dosomething "$aa" &
                    dosomething "$bb" &
                    dosomething "$cc" &
                    dosomething "$dd" &
                    dosomething "$ee" &
                    dosomething "$ff" &
                    dosomething "$gg" &
                    dosomething "$hh" &
                    dosomething "$ii" &
                    dosomething "$jj" &
                    wait
done < somefile
```

Where `dosomething` is just an example function/application that do `something` with the specific line (which is represented by the variable next to it).

Essentially this work fine. Just wanted to make this work/look better by using arrays instead, but not sure how to format this so it use arrays...

Where it would generate variable names (only alpha, no number as that might create problem with the usual numbered variable, such as $1 etc) for N amount of job.

To prevent confusion: each read in the script above does "one line" each, so each read = one line. Meaning each iteration there are reading one line X amount of read. The `wait` at the end of each iteration wait for all jobs to finish.

Example:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25917526/12349101) answer does a similar thing that I'm doing, except it read from two file, two lines (one for each) at the same time. Mine does way more.

PS: I'm aware i could do something better using `parallel`, `xargs` or something else, but prefer to only use bash/POSIX if possible.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: from your script i have no idea what you're trying to do... Why i, a, b, c ... etc. How do you know how many times `read` you need? Why not one `read` per iteration and a `wait` after the loop?

Comment: because then it would only read "one line" per "iteration"...here it does as many lines per iteration as there are "read" so, i guess it's in parallel as i described in my post above :) @pLumo

Comment: This seems extremely complicated... whats wrong with a regular loop with `read`? You can still execute your commands in the background (what you call "in parallel")

Comment: because then it'll only do a *single line* per iteration?? this wouldn't be fast enough, i mean, i believe i didn't leave any explanation of the code above (do tell me if i did so i can edit it in) @Panki

Comment: And your approach somehow does not? I am confused, to say the least. What do you define as "iteration"? I thought the goal here is to run a command with every line in the file? So iterations = linecount

Comment: iteration = each time the group of read execute at once. I tried many example of "regular loop with `read`" but this wasn't as fast as this. I believe what you're asking may be offtopic given the above code work, and what I'm asking isn't "why" but "how" to make this into an array (instead of having to type each read manually for N lines every time) @Panki

Comment: Its not clear why you'd want this in an array, or what benefits that would give. [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Then, what would be the preferred way to do this? I don't mind any suggestion (especially if it retain the speed the above code has) @Panki :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121146/discussion-between-nordine-lotfi-and-panki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does not use arrays, but keep a counter to determine when to wait.

```bsh
count=0
while read -r line; do
    dosomething "$line" &
    ((++count % 35 == 0)) && wait
done < file
```

Parenthetically, do you not like the variable `y`?

One big issue with your code: you have to successfully read all 35 lines to `dosomething` with them. while processing the file, suppose you read `a` and `b` but hit EOF while attempting to read `c` -- `read` returns non-zero, the while condition fails and the loop breaks without processing `$a` and `$b`.

---

With an array, not simpler:

```bsh
mapfile -t lines < file
len=${#lines[@]}
i=0
while ((i < len)); do
    for _ in {1..35}; do
        dosomething "${lines[i]}" &
        ((i++))
        ((i == len)) && break
    done
    wait
done
```

Comment: haha, i didn't noticed i forgot to use the variable `y` :) I actually don't have anything against it, the more the merrier (for the number of jobs that is).

Comment: Interesting. I guess i didn't thought as far as i thought when i came up with the array method hmm. Although, i do roughly recall getting to the end of a huge file, and the loop didn't _entirely_ fail when there was less than 35 lines (it did fail for individual lines but not the for the rest of first couple of lines that catch the rest of the file), unless i checked wrong...